# ActionScript 3 - Removing Duplicates in ArrayCollection

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, arraycollection

I have an ArrayCollection of a list of usernames and user id's. In this list there are duplicates that I need to remove. I've searched the internet and while there are a lot of example of this using Arrays, I can't find any clear examples using ArrayCollection's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The should be simpler then the other solution.

```
function removeDuplicatesInArray(val:*, index:uint, array:Array):Boolean {
  return array.indexOf(val) == array.lastIndexOf(val);
}

function removeDuplicatesInCollection(collection:ArrayCollection):ArrayCollection {
  collection.source = collection.source.filter(removeDuplicatesInArray);

  return collection;
}
```

Comment: simpler, but slower. It has complexity ~O(N^2), while @rawry one is ~O(N). Better solution would be without using _indexOf_ at all.

Comment: There is always room for optimisation. I wanted to provide a simple solution which is easy to understand. I don't think it's productive to provide complicated solutions for non complicated questions. If it is too slow, we'll make it faster. But if filtering for unique items is a problem for someone, I think it's wrong to offer code the asker will have trouble to understand. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @fsbmain - That would depend on the requirements now wouldn't it? Just because you can build a mansion doesn't mean you should when a tree fort will do. 10,000 elements? Sure... 100? probably not. Also, that solution is at best O(N) and at worst 2O(N).

Comment: @Mike Petty and Florian I agree with both of you, there isn't only white and only black, everything is gray ) The rawry solution may have more memory consumption for instance, but in general I prefer faster solution, nobody knows how many elements does author filter and how often. Mike, the _filter_ method it's self is O(N) and _indexOf_ + _lastIIndexOf_ is 2*O(N), so final complexity is O(N)*2O(N) ~ 2O(N^2) in worth case.

Comment: 2*O(N) = O(2N) = O(N)

Comment: I'm all for iterative development (build only what you need, etc), but ```O(n^2)``` for something that naively is ```O(n)``` is pretty grossly inefficient.  I also think there's a typo: shouldn't ```removeDublicatesInArray``` be ```removeDuplicatesInArray```?

Comment: this doesn't even work. if the array has 2 same elements it will remove both of them

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I found after quick googling.

```
//takes an AC and the filters out all duplicate entries
public function getUniqueValues (collection : ArrayCollection) : ArrayCollection {
    var length : Number = collection.length;
    var dic : Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    //this should be whatever type of object you have inside your AC
    var value : Object;
    for(var i : int= 0; i < length; i++){
        value = collection.getItemAt(i);
        dic[value] = value;
    }

    //this bit goes through the dictionary and puts data into a new AC
    var unique = new ArrayCollection();
    for(var prop:String in dic){
        unique.addItem(dic[prop]);
    }
    return unique;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find solutions for the array you can do the same with the ArrayCollection. You can change `arrayCollection.source` and `arrayCollection` will be changed too. In general, we can assume that ArrayCollection is wrapper for Array.

Answer (score 0):

Array contain a filter function and we can make use of it as following.

```
            var ar:Array = ["Joe","Bob","Curl","Curl"];
            var distinctData = ar.filter(function(itm, i){
                return ar.indexOf(itm)== i; 
            });

            Alert.show(distinctData.join(","));
```

Or better yet

```
            Array.prototype.distinct = function():*
            {
                var arr:Array = this as Array;
                return arr.filter(function(itm, i){
                    return (this as Array).indexOf(itm)== i; 
                },arr);
            };              

            var ar:Array = ["Joe","Bob","Curl","Curl"];
            Alert.show(ar.distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDuplicateElement(_arr:Array):Array{
    //set new Dictionary
    var lDic:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    for each(var thisElement:* in _arr){
        //All values of duplicate entries will be overwritten
        lDic[thisElement] = true;
    }
    _arr = [];
    for(var lKey:* in lDic){
       _arr.push(lKey);
    }
    return _arr;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.